# Auto enable bluetooth on android phone

Tags: android, bluetooth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable/disable bluetooth programmatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806536/how-to-enable-disable-bluetooth-programmatically-in-android)

I'm trying to write an App that will turn Bluetooth on to scan for devices and connect to a specific device, if it is in range.
My problem is how do I turn the Bluetooth on if it is off?
If I use :

```
if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
}
```

there is still a question for the user if he wants to turn the Bluetooth on.
Can I turn if on programmatically without the users involvement?

Comment: Please check below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806536/how-to-enable-disable-bluetooth-programmatically-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no possibility to turn on some phone features like BT, GPS, WiFi without user action. It's android feature introduced in 1.6(?) due to security concerns.