# How to disable the Bluetooth in android?

Tags: android, checkbox, bluetooth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable/disable bluetooth programmatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806536/how-to-enable-disable-bluetooth-programmatically-in-android)

I'm a newbie in android development. I'm not able to disable Bluetooth in my app. Here I've used a checkbox.Enabling of which enables the bluetooth but while disabling it remains enable.. What do I do?

My code:

```
enable_chkbox=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkboxenable);
enable_chkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(buttonView.isChecked())
        {
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
            else if(!buttonView.isChecked())//updated
            {
                mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
            //finish();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Android Manifest file permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3806536/940096)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `else if` code is of no use.
Try this.

```
  BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();    
  if(buttonView.isChecked())
    {
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
    }
    else 
    {
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
           //finish();
     }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dev.. You have solved my problem.. :

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your else is misplaced. It should be

```
if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    } 
}
else {
    mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
    // finish();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code -

```
enable_chkbox=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkboxenable);
enable_chkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(buttonView.isChecked())
    {
        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();    
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) 
        {
            // do something
        }else
        { 
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable(); 
        }
        }
    }
});
```