# Is it possible to lock the bluetooth in android device for a specific time period

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am able to disable Bluetooth using Bluetooth API`s Disable method .but my requirement is also to prevent the user interaction for Bluetooth when my apps is running.Is there any way to prevent the user interaction i.e when the user try to enable Bluetooth the app will block it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a small piece of code that needs to be written to disable/block bluetooth access. However, if you want to modify the functionality lagely, rooting is the solution. However, this post is already having relevance to the one noted ast : [How to enable/disable bluetooth programmatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806536/how-to-enable-disable-bluetooth-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: You are right..But my requirement is to prevent the user not to enable BT when my app is running(i.e one type of lock for BT)