# How to turn on bluetooth programatically

Tags: android, bluetooth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable/disable bluetooth programmatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806536/how-to-enable-disable-bluetooth-programmatically-in-android)

Hi I m developing an application in which Bluetooth has to be turned on programatically can you please tell me as to how to do that step by step thanks in advance

Comment: Did you searched about this question?

Answer (score 3):

This code works for me.   You can try this

```
  BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();    
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
           //Play with bluetooth
        }else{ 
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable(); 
        }
```