# Shut down bluetooth after closing connection

Tags: android, bluetooth, headphones

I recently bought a bluetooth headphone to pair with my Experia Z3. I was wondering what code I might use to develop an app that will automatically shut off bluetooth on my phone after it loses connection with the headphones. I tried looking into some code but I couldn't really find what I was looking for.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a question that may help your thought process[Enable/Disable Bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806536/how-to-enable-disable-bluetooth-programmatically-in-android).You can build upon this to your specific task.

Comment: Thank you! I'd seen that question before but didn't really know how to implement it, now that I look at it again it becomes more clear.