# Android Wear Bluetooth turning on/off using coding

Tags: android, bluetooth, wear-os, connectivity, android-wear-notification

Is it possible turn on and off Bluetooth by coding in Android Wear? I couldn't find anything online.

It's possible in Android mobile apps, but I want to know whether the same is possible with android watches.

Comment: I want to turn off my Moto 360's Bluetooth automatically when no devices is found, and start scanning after an regular interval.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable/disable bluetooth programmatically in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806536/how-to-enable-disable-bluetooth-programmatically-in-android)